# How to connect a CITIZEN printer to Xamarin.Forms app?

Tags: xamarin.forms, printers

I'm developing a mobile app with xamarin.forms, this app make a bluetooth connection to the CITIZEN printer. The printer has a plugin for xamarin.forms. This plugin is imported into the project; but when I try connect the printer from the application, it returns the following error:

```
Excepcion: Didn't find class "com.citizen.jpos.printer.CPCLPrinter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.facturaimpresion2.x_0-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.facturaimpresion2.x_0-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]. StackTrace:   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+Types.FindClass (System.String classname) [0x00129] in <bf671abdfa384ce99d758b134b9dd5bf>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniType..ctor (System.String classname) [0x00006] in <bf671abdfa384ce99d758b134b9dd5bf>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniType.GetCachedJniType (Java.Interop.JniType& cachedType, System.String classname) [0x00018] in <bf671abdfa384ce99d758b134b9dd5bf>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers.get_JniPeerType () [0x0000c] in <bf671abdfa384ce99d758b134b9dd5bf>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.get_JniPeerType () [0x00014] in <bf671abdfa384ce99d758b134b9dd5bf>:0 
  at Java.Interop.JniPeerMembers+JniInstanceMethods.StartCreateInstance (System.String constructorSignature, System.Type declaringType, Java.Interop.JniArgumentValue* parameters) [0x0003f] in <bf671abdfa384ce99d758b134b9dd5bf>:0 
  at Com.Citizen.Jpos.Printer.CPCLPrinter..ctor () [0x00034] in <e141e43239ef42c4af494152c936c094>:0 
  at Plugin.CitizenXamarinSDK.CitizenXamarinCPCLImplementation.connect (System.String macAddress) [0x0009b] in <1427ae75e5b64afe9c92e8161f8405b8>:0 
  at facturaImpresion2._0.MainPage.OnConnectableDeviceSelection (System.Object sender, Xamarin.Forms.SelectedItemChangedEventArgs e) [0x00119] in C:\Users\segador\source\repos\FacturaImpresion\facturaImpresion2.0\facturaImpresion2.0\MainPage.xaml.cs:537 
  --- End of managed Java.Lang.ClassNotFoundException stack trace ---
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.citizen.jpos.printer.CPCLPrinter" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.companyname.facturaimpresion2.x_0-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.companyname.facturaimpresion2.x_0-1/lib/arm, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
    at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.CellAdapter.n_onItemClick(Native Method)
    at crc643f46942d9dd1fff9.CellAdapter.onItemClick(CellAdapter.java:89)
    at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:305)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1185)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3222)
    at android.widget.AbsListView$3.run(AbsListView.java:4138)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:194)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5576)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:955)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:750)
    Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.citizen.jpos.printer.CPCLPrinter
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
        ... 15 more
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

Comment: did you install the package in both the Android and Forms projects?

Comment: yes, I did. The plugin is in both project. thanks for answer.